# Jquery to change span tag content from array on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, replace

I need to change the content of span tag with class u when somebody clicks on the p tag with their respective id tag which is passed as parameter to the function so that function can convert that number to numeric and that numeric value from an array is accessed and that is added as new value completely replacing the previous value.

```
//html code
    <span id="u">My point</span>
    <p class="current" id="one" onclick="chan('one')">My point</p>
    <p id="two" onclick="chan('two')">text2</p>
    <p id="three" onclick="chan('three')">text2</p>
    <p id="four" onclick="chan('four')">text2</p>
    <p id="five" onclick="chan('five')">text2</p>
    <p id="six" onclick="chan('six')">text2</p>
    <p id="seven" onclick="chan('seven')" >text2</p>



//javascript code

    var titl = ['My point',
                'text2',
                'text3',
                'text4',
                'text5',
                'text6',
                'text7'
                ];

     function chan(pin){
        if(pin="two"){
                it = 1;
              }
              else if(pin="one"){
                it = 0;
              }
              else if(pin="three"){
                it = 2;
              }
              else if(pin="four"){
                it = 3;
              }
              else if(pin="five"){
                it = 4;
              }
              else if(pin="six"){
                it = 5;
              }
              else if(pin="seven"){
                it = 6;
              }

              document.getElementById("u").innerHTML = titl[it;
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<p class='js-load-number' data-number='0'>one</p>
<p class='js-load-number' data-number='2'>three</p>
<p class='js-load-number' data-number='3'>four</p>
```

And the jquery:

```
var updateScore = function() {
    var numberFromClicked = $(this).data('number');
    $('#u').html(numberFromClicked);
}
$('.js-load-number').click(updateScore);
```

This leaves you with much cleaner code which will work and be nice to you in the future.

I've removed the `onclick` attributes from the HTML and used jquery's [`.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) method, which takes a predefined function as an argument. The separate function is clearer and more re-usable.

I've defined the HTML data as a data attribute, which is a better way of storing data in HTML. It's accessed with jquerys [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method. You can put whatever number you like in the data attribute so there's no need for the conversion array in the javascript.

We also use the `$(this)` construct in jquery to refer to the element which triggered the event (in this case a click event)

Answer (score 0):

There is mistake in class and id for U, Also some mistake in javascript code : I have change code

```
//html code
    <span class="u" id="u">My point</span>
    <p class="current" id="one" onclick="chan('one')">My point</p>
    <p id="two" onclick="chan('two')">text2</p>
    <p id="three" onclick="chan('three')">text2</p>
    <p id="four" onclick="chan('four')">text2</p>
    <p id="five" onclick="chan('five')">text2</p>
    <p id="six" onclick="chan('six')">text2</p>
    <p id="seven" onclick="chan('seven')" >text2</p>



//javascript code

    var titl = ['My point',
                'text2',
                'text3',
                'text4',
                'text5',
                'text6',
                'text7'
                ];

     function chan(pin){
        if(pin="two"){
                it = 1;
              }
              else if(pin="one"){
                it = 0;
              }
              else if(pin="three"){
                it = 2;
              }
              else if(pin="four"){
                it = 3;
              }
              else if(pin="five"){
                it = 4;
              }
              else if(pin="six"){
                it = 5;
              }
              else if(pin="seven"){
                it = 6;
              }

              document.getElementById("u").innerHTML = titl[it];
     }
```

Comment: what was mistake in javascript part